# Can we embedd a ComboBox or a TextCtrl on the ObjectListView of wxPython?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

If this is possible, can you show some code example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectListView is just a nice wrapper around the ListCtrl. To my knowledge, the ListCtrl does not support the embedding of other widgets. You could create a popup dialog when double-clicking a cell and do it that way. Otherwise, you would have to use the UltimateListCtrl. That widget DOES allow widget embedding because it's a custom widget rather than a native one.